# Operator preference between sign and exponent

Tags: notation

I have seen different operand preference between several application regarding sign and exponent operator:

```
-7^2
```

Is understood some times as (excel and similar)

```
(-7)^2
```

And others like (wolframalpha)

```
-(7^2)
```

Which is the correct interpretation? I would like some normative answer/reference, a simple "opinion" would be useless even if correct.

Comment: The correct interpretation in mathematics of $-7^2$ is $-7\cdot 7.$ This is a power (up to the sign) with basis $7$ and not $-7.$ Thus the result is $-49.$ It is different from $(-7)^2.$ In this case we have a power with basis $-7.$ Thus, it means $(-7)\cdot (-7),$ which is equal to $49.$

Comment: Thank you. Is there any normative document to corroborate it? Is not that I do not trust, but I need to convince several people about it, which will probably imply some hours of work for them. So I need some "prove" of it.

Comment: Is this link http://www.algebrahelp.com/lessons/simplifying/oops helpful?

Comment: As I understand the question, the operator preference is a matter of decision and not something deductible. Is there any standard for this kind of conventions?  Correct me if I am wrong, but algebrahelp.com is not any standardization entity.

Comment: What about http://cpm.org/about-cpm/? There you can find http://pdfs.cpm.org/skillBuilders/MC/MC_Order_of_Operations.pdf This is order of operations any mathematician uses.

Comment: By the way, the part about needing to convince other people sounds like that is the **real problem**, not whether there is any standardization of mathematical terminology. In fact it sounds like the type of people who would rather trust a calculator rather than learn any mathematics. The thing about mathematics is that theorem are true regardless of the terminology you choose to express it. Of course we have to use some language that others understand to express it, but it really is irrelevant to the real content and implications of a theorem.

Comment: If it causes so much trouble, simply define the operator precedence in the documentation itself! For example see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence, which is for one particular programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered by the standard "Pedmas" ("Please excuse my dear aunt Sally") or "Bedmas" to our British friends. 
 First parentheses (Brackets) then exponentials then division then multiplication then subtraction.

In "-7^2", the "negative" is multiplying by -1 so the exponent, 2, takes precedence.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "normative answer," there is no "normative reference." There is no Holy Bible of Mathematics, no Supreme Court of Mathematical Notations. There are only people who find different conventions useful at different times. If you want to use Excel, you have to do it the way Excel does it; if you want to use Wolfram Alpha, you have to do it the way Wolfram Alpha does it. I wouldn't even know how to attach any meaning to a statement such as, "Excel is wrong", or "Wolfram is wrong".

It's a bit like asking for a normative answer as to which is right, "hat", or "chapeau". One is right in London, the other is right in Paris.

Your question is not about Mathematics, but about sociology.

Comment: A standard is not about saying who is wrong or correct, but about deciding a shared language to communicate correctly. Like in physics, 1m is defined by the CIPM, you could use another self-invented unit for length, but probably nobody will understand you. We all agree that 2*3+5 is 11 and not 16, but if an entity put that on paper with a reference (e.g. Whatever-087), you may just say "I follow Whatever-087" and anybody could communicate with you without any issue.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: You don't get the point. Ultimately mathematics relies on natural language. Using natural language we first define certain otherwise undefinable mathematical terms, and then we can use these mathematical terms to define more terms. Both syntax and semantics of these terms must be precisely spelt out, and thereafter we just use them. Of course, we don't keep parroting what has already been said and become the de facto terminology. So to understand correctly any mathematical writing you need to know the current convention. That is why Gerry calls it sociology.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: To give you a proper analogy, suppose I set up a website stating that it is the new official website for the CIPM, and on it I redefine the metre. Who determines which is the real CIPM? Is there even such a thing as "**the real** CIPM"? Furthermore, even if there is a CIPM, so what? Hardly anybody bothers to follow standards strictly. You don't use light to measure your height, you use a ruler made in some place that again didn't use light but some other measurement device to manufacture the ruler, and that device was made in ...

Comment: Well, if you guys think standardization is useless, is another matter, and that at least give a point to my question.
@user21820: Who determine which is the real CIPM? well, we have international laws for that, so if you like your freedom, do not try to  substitute any registered commercial entity. "Hardly anybody bothers to follow standards": Again, if you sell a device which is supposed to be USB and you do not follow the USB standard 100%, they could relay you to justice. Of course nobody will bother about your height, but just take the example of volkswagen.

Comment: "A standard is not about saying who is wrong or correct, but about deciding a shared language to communicate correctly." Your question was not about communication, but about computer programs. If you want to "communicate correctly" with Excel, then $-7^2$ is $49$. If you want to "communicate correctly" with Alpha, then $-7^2$ is $-49$.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: What Gerry said, and if you want to communicate correctly with most mathematicians alive today, then $-7^2 = -49$ and $f(x)^2 = (f(x))^2$ for any function $f$ and ... `list all current mathematical conventions here'.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: exactly!,  meaning it does NOT follow the same standard as usually does Mathematicians. Whenever this "standard" is "de facto" or managed by any entity. I feel like living in a different world than you: in my planet the earth 21th, all is standardized, from computer science, environment care, food quality, management, processes, aviation, etc. It seem believable that Math is not. I will consider that as a "No, there is no recognized standards for mathematics".

Comment: You have to decide whether you want "recognized standards" or a "standardization entity". If you want the latter, you are sod out of luck. There is no Academie Francaise that rules on mathematical notation. But if you are willing to settle for recognized standards, as @user21820 suggests, the recognized standard – the *convention* to which people adhere when, say, they write textbooks (but *not* when they write software) – is that $-7^2$ is $-(7^2)$.

Comment: @AdrianMaire: I would say that there is actually the same level of standardization in Mathematics as in other things in general. Just for example until very recently even the internet wasn't following almost all "official" protocols but rather "de facto" ones, more like whatever was chosen first and was useful and stuck around long enough. Similarly, even today some parts of the world use the SI unit kg for mass while others still use pounds. One aviation accident even arose due to the different units used at different airports!

Comment: @AdrianMaire: In both cases, the point is that if the notation used is defined unambiguously, then there is no need for one single standard. Multiple standards have always existed for nearly everything in history. One could say that perhaps the established mathematics journals can be taken as a reference point for mathematical terminology, or perhaps Wolfram, but they are all separate and do not necessary agree on all terminology. Neither do they have to. However, they **should** agree on all mathematical theorems!